# How to get total duration and total distance via way points in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on getting directions using google maps, I have found number of solutions how to get the distance and duration from source to destination, when we have way points,

We can get using something like this,

```
angular.forEach(response.routes[0].legs, function (value, key) {
     totalDistance += parseFloat(value.distance.value)
     totalDuration += parseInt(value.duration.value)
});
```

If we work around something like this i get the distance, then i should convert it back to KM with comma, and for duration again i need to convert it back to Hours, min, sec format. Rather than doing all this, is there any direct attribute or method available to get from origin to destination.

Answer (score 0):

No, `duration` and `distance` at `DirectionsLeg` level is the best you can have.